# React functional component re-renders with old data

Tags: reactjs

I have this functional component that is used as a child component. Like this:

```
//... in the ParentComponent
<ChildComponent
  id={somevalue}
/>
```

and the Child Component looks like this:

```
const ChildComponent = ({
    id
}) => {
const [rawData, setRawData] = useState([]);
const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
// ... do some time consuming calculations
        SetProcessedData(data);
}, [rawData]);

useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect');

// fetch data with axios and ...
        () => {
            const reloadData = async () => {
                axios.request({
                   url,
                   data,
                   ...config,
                })
                .then((result) => {
                   SetRawData(data);
                })
 
            };
       reloadData();
}, [id]);

console.log('Render');
return(
   {processedData.map( ....) }
);
}
```

The first time the ChildComponent is render everything works like charm.
The problem occurs when somevalue and the prop (id) is changed.

The child sees the new props and rerenders the component AND calls useEffect[id]
The problem is that the render happens BEFORE the useEffect so the processedData state is still old.

I tried to avoid the first rerender by setting a isLoading variable but the first place I can do it is the useEffect[id] which is called AFTER the rerender.

So the console shows:

```
Render
useEffect
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Need to see more of the `useEffect` where you fetch data with axios. Are you waiting until the http call returns before calling `setRawData` or are you doing it immediately?

Comment: It's not clear why this would even be an issue. The visibility of `processedData.map` should not be *so* tied to the previous render that it breaks on recieving new props. Why is it an issue that old `processedData` is visible for a split second before replacing it with a loading spinner or similar?

Comment: Yes this is the problem. For a moment the old data is displayed then the loading spinner and then the new data.

Comment: The question is: how to make useEffect to be called before the render happens when the props are changed.

Comment: You can't, that's not how `useEffect` works, it will always be called after rendering is complete. It you set a spinnner immediately before calling `reloadData` then the UI should not appear out of sync, or at least, I can't see how it would given the context you've shown.

Comment: The problem is that the parent component already displays new data and the child component shows still old data. I understand that I should move the state to the parent component, but the child component is somewhere else used directly, without the parent..